# File Handling in C Print out the reverse String in the output from the input

Tags: c, string, file, file-handling

Okay, so i have a lot of problems with file handling and strings in C. The point of this task is to reverse the string from the output and to convert lower letters to upper and vice-versa. For example i have to get an output of ENALPOREa from an Aeroplane. I have to have 2 files. An input file where i have written Aeroplane and an output file where i have got ENALPOREa. Any help is appreciated !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void inputOfAString(const char*nameOfTheFile){
FILE *fin = fopen(nameOfTheFile,"w");

if(fin == NULL){
   printf("Error");
   exit(1);
}

char s[20];
fgets(s,20,stdin);
fprintf(fin,"%s",s);

fclose(fin);
}


void readTheString(const char *inputOfTheFile,const char*outputOfTheFile){
   FILE *fout = fopen(outputOfTheFile,"w");
   FILE *fin = fopen(inputOfTheFile,"r");
   if(fout == NULL || fin == NULL){
       printf("Error");
       exit(1);
   }
   char s[20];
   while(!feof(fin)){
       fgets(s,20,inputOfTheFile);
       for(int i = 0;i<20;i++){
           if(s[i] == isupper(s[i])){
               s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
           }else{
               s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
           }
       }
       fputs(s,fout);
   }

   fclose(fout);
   fclose(fin);
}

int main(){
   inputOfAnString("input1.txt");
   readTheString("input1.txt","output1.txt");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question or described any errors/incorrect behaviours. Please review - [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [Why `while(!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: `s[i] = islower(s[i])` should be `s[i] = tolower(s[i])`

Comment: And `if (s[i] == isupper(s[i]))` should be `if (isupper(s[i]))`

Comment: Shouldn't the `else if` be the opposite condition? And if it's the opposite, you should just use `else`.

Comment: The loop where you lower-case `s` could be made much simpler, and without possibly going out beyond the null-terminator: `for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(s); ++i) { s[i] = tolower(s[i]); }`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Better to use `for(int i = 0; s[i]; i++){` rather than call `strlen()` repeatedly.

Comment: Worst Vayne Antartic, `tolower()` in both side of the `if()`?

Comment: Instead of `printf("Error")`, write an informative message to stderr with `perror(nameOfTheFile)`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Agree that the error message could/should be made more informative, yet failed values can have _bad_ attributes to them - like the file name containing control characters (e.g. `'\n'`) ,  etc.  Care is warranted printing _bad_ data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the result of `fgets()`, not `feof()`.
(Whatever text or instructor suggested `feof()` - treat with suspicion).

Use the result of `isupper()` as T/F test.

One branch should use `toupper()`

Iterate to the end of the string, which may be less than 20.

```
   char s[20];
   //while(!feof(fin)){
   //    fgets(s,20,inputOfTheFile);
   while(fgets(s, sizeof s, inputOfTheFile)) {
       // for(int i = 0; i < 20;i++){
       for(int i = 0; s[i];i++){
           // if(s[i] == isupper(s[i])){
           if(isupper(s[i])){
               s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
           }else{
               //s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
               s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
           }
       }
       fputs(s,fout);
   }
```

---

Advanced: use `unsigned char` for avoid calling `is...(), to...()` with negative values.

Tight alternative

```
   #define S_SIZE 20
   char s[S_SIZE];
   while (fgets(s, sizeof s, inputOfTheFile)) {
       const unsigned char *p = (const unsigned char *) s;
       while (*p) {
           if(isupper(*p)) {
               *p = tolower(*p);
           } else {
               *p = toupper(*p);
           }
           p++;
       }
       fputs(s, fout);
   }
```